# What's wrong with this SpamAssassin rule?

Tags: spamassassin

```
body LOCAL_SHORT_BODY /^.{2,120}$/
score LOCAL_SHORT_BODY 0.4
describe LOCAL_SHORT_BODY Short body
```

I included this in my local.cf, and gave it a low score as it's not really a great indicator of spam on its own, but in conjunction with other rules I have, it works well.

The problem is, even long emails seem to trigger this rule. Why? I'm pretty sure my regex above is correct (a body of 2-120 chars).

Comment: Aren't you saying match any character (.) two to 120 times?

Comment: Yes. I want to match any email that is 2-120 chars in length. Is the above expression considered Perl regex? Do I need the =~ symbol before it?

Comment: Though it's not like it's NOT matching text.. it's matching anything/everything.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering, it seems at first glance to be correct ^ start . any character {2,120} between 2 and 120 $ end, what I'm wondering is if it could be saying, well, up to 120 characters can be matched in a 2000 character document...

Comment: So, if you add =~m/ what happens?

Comment: Not sure what m/ is. Changed line to `body LOCAL_SHORT_BODY =~ /^.{2,120}$/` and `spamassassin --lint` failed.

Comment: I dunno, it's how all the rules on the spamassassin linked perl regex page were written. Oddly enough the only page that's still functional.  http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your rule:

```perl
body LOCAL_SHORT_BODY /^.{2,120}$/
score LOCAL_SHORT_BODY 0.4
describe LOCAL_SHORT_BODY Short body
```

says that *any line* in the email has 2-120 characters in it.  Almost all mail will match this.

Because whitespace is specially treated, I'd also steer you away from the "right" regex solution of `/^.{2,120}$/s` but instead I would recommend:

```perl
ifplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::BodyEval
if can(Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::BodyEval::has_check_body_length)
body __LOCAL_BODY_LT_2     eval:check_body_length('2')
body __LOCAL_BODY_LT_120   eval:check_body_length('120')
meta LOCAL_SHORT_BODY      !__LOCAL_BODY_LT_2 && __LOCAL_BODY_LT_120
score LOCAL_SHORT_BODY     0.4
describe LOCAL_SHORT_BODY  Short body
endif
endif
```

I don't recall when `check_body_length()` was added, but when it comes to stuff like SpamAssassin, you always want the latest version.  The above conditionals ensure that you don't break anything if you're stuck on an older version.